# How can I run a csh script from a tcl script, csh script contain bsub command?

Tags: tcl, csh

I am trying to run a csh script within tcl script.  The csh script contains bsub command  in it. When i am trying to run script it is erroring out saying bsub: Command not found.

Script specimen :

```
exec cp -r x  ../                           
cd ../../my_area                          
exec cp -r y ../../                           
cd ../../my_scripts                 
exec /bin/csh/  aim.csh  >@stdout 2>@stderr                   
# also tried set hd aim.csh , exec /bin/csh $hd >@stdout 2>@stderr}
```

details of aim.csh

```
setenv IDC $d                                                
setenv LGH $f                                          
set error   $e                                                
bsub -q normal  -db  <path>
```

Comment: Apart from the unnecessary redirections, `exec /bin/csh/  aim.csh` should do fine, **provided that aim.csh is in your working directory**. _command not found_ means that `bsub` is not in your `PATH` (or, in csh-speak, in your `path`).

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to invoke the script is like this:

```
exec /bin/csh aim.csh >@stdout 2>@stderr
```

You *might* want to make sure that the `aim.csh` file exists prior to running. It's important to do this after any `cd` call; that changes where the code will look for `aim.csh`.

If you have a problem with `bsub` not being on the executable search path, that's properly neither Tcl's nor csh's fault. (I've no idea where it would be, and can't remember which package supplies it.) You can extend the executable search path from your Tcl code if you need to:

```
# Before calling exec; after is too late
append env(PATH) :/path/to/directory
```

For example, if `bsub` were actually `/opt/local/somewhere/bin/bsub`, then you'd do:

```
append env(PATH) :/opt/local/somewhere/bin
```

A truly *proper* way to do this is with this procedure:

```
proc addToPath {directory} {
    global env tcl_platform
    if {[file type $directory] ne "directory"} {
        error "must pass a directory name"
    }
    append env(PATH) $tcl_platform(pathSeparator) [file nativename $directory]
    return
}

addToPath /opt/local/somewhere/bin
```

But the simple `append` is good enough for non-portable code.